# Why does the query run fast with a small number of rows, but takes hours for many rows

Tags: oracle

oracle version:10.2.0.4.0

table: va_edges_detail_temp

The fields are the following:

- source_label: varchar2
- target_label: varchar2
- edge_weight: number

The following query:

```
select  v.*, level 
from va_edges_detail_temp v
start with v.source_label = 'smith'
connect by nocycle prior v.target_label = v.source_label
order by level;
```

When there are 552 rows in the table it only takes 0.005 seconds.

When there are 6600 rows in the table, execution never finishes. I waited for hours, but it does not finish, returns no result but shows no error either.

What's the matter?

Comment: The answer may be related at least in part to how many `'smith'` you have in the two tables. If you have more than one starting point, the number of rows generated by the hierarchical query grows geometrically. Do a `select count(*) from va_edges_detail_temp where source_label = 'smith'` on the two versions of the table and see what you get.

Comment: Based solely on information you've provided someone can only guess the answer - you provided no sample data, you've provided no information on your table structure, whether there are any indexes created on that table or not, you've provided no execution plan for your query - basically nothing.

Comment: being a "_temp" table i'd suggest you probably have no indexes.. and with the larger dataset the full table scans become increasing prohibitive.  try adding indexes to source_label and target_label. collect stats and see how that goes..  failing that you coudl post your explain plan..

Answer (score 1):

Well, its too wide question.

In common it depends on your data. And count of rows provided via connecting of rows in va_edges_detail_temp. Its may be **n^2** or **n^4** or 
even **n!**.

In any case its may increase dramatically and may not

Another part of performance its memory size. If resulted rows set are 
fits into RAM oracle do  it in memory. If not Oracle will try to fold data into hard drive. Its time-expensive operation in common.

Comment: the purpose is to find the level of person in the person-relation tree.

Comment: The purpose of the code is to find the level of person in the person-relation tree. I extract the same set of data to the a C++ program. the c++ program is a traditional tree layout algorithm. the C++ program accomplished in 3 minutes. So, is there may be  computation bottleneck for oracle to calculate a large amount of memory computing tasks. In other words,  whether oracle is not suitable for memory consuming computing task?